# Photoshop Scripting: Creating a selection, then fitting a text box inside

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

Using Javascript for Photoshop (ExtendScript) I am trying make a dynamic text box.

My end goal is a script that the user writes their own text into a new window pop up, then that text is positioned in the bottom 10% of the image, scaled dynamically to fit the bottom 10% of an image.

So, whatever the dimensions of the lower 10% (created by resizeCanvas argument) the text always fits within it comfortably. So when the user adds a few words it does not look too small and when they add a longer sentence it does not overspill.

Question originally asked here (with pictures) https://forums.adobe.com/message/10952562#10952562

Example Start Image:

[start image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czSau.png)

Window Pop up :

[custom PopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiPev.png)

Small Text Outcome:

[outcome1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ahqt.png)

Long Text Outcome:

[outcome 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Flf.png)

This is where I am currently:

```js
#target Photoshop  
  
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;  
app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.PIXELS;  
var doc = app.activeDocument;  
var hgt10 = doc.height / 10;  
var FillColor = new SolidColor;  
FillColor.rgb.hexValue = 'ff0000';  
var newHgt = doc.height + hgt10  
doc.resizeCanvas(doc.width, newHgt, AnchorPosition.TOPCENTER);  
  
  var win = new Window('dialog', "Custom Text");  
  var grp1 = win.add('group');  
  grp1.alignChildren = "top";  
  var txt = grp1.add('edittext', [0, 0, 300, 150], "Write your message", {multiline: true, scrolling: true});  
  txt.active = true;  
  var grp2 = win.add('group');  
  var goBtn = grp2.add('button', undefined, "Run");  
  grp2.add('button', undefined, "Cancel");  
    
  var newLyr = doc.artLayers.add();  
  newLyr.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;  
  // CONTENTS  
  var txtLyr = newLyr.textItem  
  txtLyr.font = "ArialMT"  
  txtLyr.contents = txt.text  
  var uV = new UnitValue(20,'mm')  
  txtLyr.size = UnitValue(25,'mm')  
  txtLyr.color = FillColor;  
  txtLyr.position = [25, 2200] // x, y - Need to fix position to fit in the lower 10%  
  
  goBtn.onClick = function() {  
    win.close();   
  }  
  
win.show();
```

So the areas I would like some assistance with is:

1) Getting the text to be positioned in the new area (created by the resizeCanvas argument extending by 10%)

2) Adding line breaks and automatically sizing to fit a variety of length text files into the field.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

To add line breaks, replace all `\n`s with `\r`s (at least for Windows, I have a feeling that this Mac version may require something else, but I'm not sure):

```
txtLyr.contents = txt.text.replace(/\n/gm, '\r')
```

To position text you need to know the size (that'll depend on lines number) and leading.

```
var lines = txt.text.split('\n'); //getting the number of lines
var maxSize = hgt10 / lines.length; //calculating max size for a line (including the leading) = 10% of doc height devided by lines number
newLyr.textItem.useAutoLeading = true // making sure that text uses autoleading
var leading = newLyr.textItem.autoLeadingAmount; //autoleading value is in % of text size
maxSize = maxSize / leading * 100; // recalculating text size based on leading in pixels
txtLyr.size = maxSize;
txtLyr.position = [25, originalDocHeight + maxSize]
```

Result with one line and with several lines:

[image]